# Generating and printing a form in Visual Basic 2010 Express

Tags: vb.net

I am primarily a web developer, mostly working with PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript. I was recently contacted by a local Sheriff's Office (small town word of mouth, nerds are always needed) to digitize a 4 page monstrosity of a form... because nobody could read the handwriting of the deputies.

The catch here is that this is a small town department and, while they are fancy enough to carry computers in the field, they are not connected to the Internet. Visual Basic was the first solution that came to mind and I have been scrambling to learn the basics. I am confident in my ability to organize the content of the form and perform any necessary validation but I am unsure where to begin in terms of storing each report locally (database) and printing the end result.

Another matter that makes things complicated is the fact that they want the end result to look exactly the same as the original form, only typed instead of hand written.

So, to sum things up, here are the questions I have:

1. There seem to be several options for databases in VB 2010 Express. What is the best option for LOCAL storage of records?
2. It looks as though the best way to format the form the exact way they want it to look with populated data would be to create a form within the application with just this content on it. Is this the best solution or might there be a better way - possibly outputting to another file? And if the data is put on another form, how would I go about printing it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "best" is of course subjective, so instead I'll give you some pros and cons for a database.

[SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) is a really awesome database to work with that acts almost exactly like the big paid version. Some high-level things like replication and encryption aren't supported but you don't have a need for that probably. I've built many websites that target it with zero performance problems. The downside of SQL Server Express is that you need to install it on every machine and it pretty much needs to be running all the time. It doesn't "weigh" a whole lot but its still going to be running in the background 24/7. If you create an installer from within Visual Studio/VB Express (which you should) you can check it as a prerequisite and the installer will pretty much take care of it for you. As a major security target you are opening a potential for security issues which you should be aware of.

SQLite would another great choice, there's some great [.Net wrappers available](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki). If you're used to using SQL Server or MySql you might find SQLite limiting but you get used to it. SQLite doesn't have a "database engine" and its goal is to be a very lightweight open source  SQL database system.

The third option that I'd recommend is just writing to an XML file. Simple, no engine, no tables, no third-party whatever, just raw text that anyone can parse if something breaks. **EDIT** And VB.Net has some wonderful built-in XML syntactic things such as XML literals:

```
    Dim MyXml = <Person>
                    <FirstName><%= txtFirstName.Text %></FirstName>
                    <LastName><%= txtLastName.Text %></LastName>
                </Person>
```

For the form generation, I'd recommend using something like [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/). (Free but make sure you check that the license matches yours.) Take their actual PDF Form (or create a PDF of theirs), use Acrobat or something similar to turn it into a "PDF Form" and then just use iTextSharp to fill in the form. There's a bunch of support on this site if you've got any questions about it.

Comment: Thanks so much, lots of great info! This will probably be my answer, hoping I get a few more nibbles. The initial request was actually just a PDF version of their form, but where's the fun in that? I had been looking for this very opportunity to cut my teeth on Windows dev and they gave me two months.